# 'No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'char[]'.' when use SP in Asp Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i need to use this `SP` from Sql :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetUsrsofRole] (@RoleId int)
AS
;WITH CTE_UsersInRole AS
(
    SELECT 
     U.Id AS [UserId], U.Name AS [UserName] , U.Family AS [UserFamily] , R.Id AS[RoleID],R.Name AS [RoleName]
    FROM AspNetUserRoles AU 
    INNER JOIN AspNetRoles R ON R.Id=AU.RoleId
    INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON U.ID=AU.UserId
)
SELECT
     C.RoleID,C.RoleName,C.UserFamily,C.UserId,C.UserName
FROM CTE_UsersInRole C
    WHERE C.RoleID=@RoleId
GO
```

i call this sp in asp core by this way :

```
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetUserOfRole(int id)
    {
        return TableAsNoTracking.FromSql("EXEC usp_GetUsrsofRole @RoleId", parameters: new[] { id }).ToList();
    }
```

now when i need to use this `sp` it show me this error :

> 'No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'char[]'.'

whats the problem ?? how can i solve this ?

Comment: Try without `new[]{}` like this: `return TableAsNoTracking.FromSql("EXEC usp_GetUsrsofRole @RoleId",  id).ToList();`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood it show me this error : `Must declare the scalar variable "@RoleId".'`

Comment: `return TableAsNoTracking.FromSql("EXEC usp_GetUsrsofRole @p0", id).ToList();`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood i have a property in table `IsDeleted` and now it show me this `The required column 'IsDelete' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.'`

Comment: Fail to reproduce the issue based on the existing code . Could you provide the related model definition ? And If you are using Entity Framework Core 2.x take a look at Query Types ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types).

Comment: @XueliChen i use this EFCore 2.2